# How to return fields in correct order for an ElasticSearch query

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm performing a multimatch search against an ElasticSearch index, and I want to get back the source object with fields in the same order as they were stored in.

However, when I get the response back from the ElasticSearch query, the fields are in alphabetical order (which is not particularly useful for what I'm doing). I'm fairly confident that it used to behave the desired way in a previous version of ES, but since I upgraded recently it is only returning the fields in alphabetical order.

**Edit:** Note that if I perform a standard match_all search, then I do get the fields back in the original order. I wonder if it has something to do with the multimatch query?

**Edit 2:** OK, I just ran it again and it returned the fields in a random order (not alphabetical). Maybe this is a bug in ElasticSearch?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot guarantee any order in what is returned. The source document is a plain old JSON object and [by definition](http://json.org):

> An object is an unordered set of name/value pairs.

Comment: That may be the case, but in my experience the JSON response from ElasticSearch is reliably received in the correct order in all situations except the one described above.